CI/CD Flutter Windows Pipeline
Github is showing this error in the Actions while processing the jobs:
Run thedoctor0/zip-release@master
Run $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/entrypoint.sh
D:\a\_actions\thedoctor0\zip-release\master/entrypoint.sh: line 10: cd: build/windows/runner/Release: No such file or directory


the thedoctor0/zip-release@master tryign to zip the release folder present in **build/windows/runner/Release** but the release folder is in
**build/windows/x64/runner/Release**

I want to change the directory path that can zip the relase folder
      - name: Debug Build Output
        run: |
          echo "Contents of build/windows/x64/runner/release:"
          ls build/windows/x64/runner/release
      - name: Package Release zip file
        uses: thedoctor0/zip-release@master

